# How to hide companies in AX 2012

Tags: axapta

Is it possible to hide some companies from Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 ?
 Can you please suggest. Thanks in advance.

I followed below link to restrict the companies, but all companies are visible

https://dynamicsaxtipoftheday.com/2014/04/11/restrict-user-access-to-certain-    companies-through-roles/

Comment: Please add information about what you've already tried

Comment: @valentjedi : Thanks for reply, I am trying by using security, not yet finished. Once its finish I will update same information

Comment: Welcom to Stack Overflow. Please take a look in the [help/on-Topic] what questions are on topic here. Your question is not programming related, but about configuration. Try other communities like [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or the [Administration and Setup](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33?pi53287=0&category=Administration%20and%20Setup) forum of the AX Community.

Comment: ....What FH-Inway said.  Also check if the user has administrator role in the AX environment.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving reply  @FH-Inway and ian_scho, Issue got resolved